# iPhone - where can i find a sample of GKVoiceChatClient?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, gamekit

I want to be able to let users of my iPhone app communicate using the GKVoiceChatClient classes. The documentation for the 3.0 SDK is very vague and I don't see any good samples in the Sample Code either.

Can someone please tell me where I can find some working example of in-game voice using which I can learn how to use it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an account on the Apple Developer forums, but I stumbled across this a little while ago.  I don't know if its functional but comments further along in the thread lead me to believe it is.

[Example in the Apple Developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/49791#49791)

chris.

Comment: Thanks Chris. That definitely helped!